# How to calculate the R square if not given the number of points

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

This is an interview problem I encountered and I have no idea about how to deal with it. Hope to get any hint or help for the first step.

Suppose there is a unit circle centered at origin, we randomly sample N points on it. There is also another point (K, K), where K >> 1. Now we do a linear regression to these N+1 points, please calculate the $R^2$

Comment: As N increases, you will be sampling more and more points on the unit circle. The correlation between just these points on the unit circle should then get closer and closer to 0. If you add in the extra point (K,K) with K large, my guess is that since you are adding one data point to a data set with $R^2\approx 0$, we should see $R^2$ increase toward 1 as N grows.

Comment: @Arbutus I would have expected almost the opposite: a correlation of $1$ when $N=1$ and usually to reducing as $N$ increases, probably towards $0$